# Atom editor not tracking changes and updating the application

Tags: atom-editor

I have been using atom editor for making changes to my application code. I recently made a change in my directory - deleted `.git` and then moved all my files to a new folder.

Now, when I open the folder in atom editor, I do not see different file colors that I use to. It doesn't track which files have changed or anything like that. When I launch the app locally using MacOS terminal, I don't see the changes reflected in my App.

It's quite strange. What do I need to do to fix this issue?

Here's my root directory in atom. All files appear is same color. something doesn't look right.

[image: directory]

Comment: Why did you delete `.git`? It's what made Atom tell you what you have changed.

Comment: I reinitialized the directory as `.git`.

Comment: Then it should work now again. Maybe you need to create an initial commit first.

Comment: Yep, it's working now.